# Multi-tenancy on Django 3.0 with MariaDB and separate databases

Tags: django, mariadb, multi-tenant

We are building a new system on Django 3.0 that requires multi-tenancy with separate databases, and we also intend to use Maria DB. I have already gone through a well-known multi-tenancy solution [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) that offers multi-tenancy with single PostgreSQL database and multiple schemas - so that doesn't solve our problem (Django 3.0 + Maria DB & multiple databases). From what I have understood, it is non-trivial to make changes in Django ORM to change the DB, so I am looking for some other solution.

How can I have multi-tenancy with DJango 3.0 if we want to use multiple database with Maria DB?

**Note:** We need '*separate databases*' due to data residency laws in most countries where this SaaS app would be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're looking django out of the box solution is difficult. This are currently all available tenant solution on django https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/multi-tenancy/ most of the available solution based on semi-isolated approach. The one maybe came close to your requirements is https://github.com/mik3y/django-db-multitenant

Comment: Yes, seen that. It doesn't help though. :(

Comment: Hi @Kelvin which approach did you used?  Thank you.